# Can hardware requirements be included in RPM dependency information? HOW?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm, yum

I want to publish my own RPM package, but it must run on some special hardware platform, I need to add some hardware requirements information to YUM repo or RPM package. how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say for which platform is the package intended using tag `ExclusiveArch`, however it just state the architecture of CPU. You cannot enforce other HW parameters (e.g presence of some card, cpu flag or some storage).

You can however do those checks in %pre section and fail if the HW is not present and therefore effectively blocking the installation (unless admin pass --no-script to rpm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I did plan to do the checks in %pre section.